# how to modify font size in an iframe target

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to create an iframe target structure, but I'm having some trouble. I can't give an example of the code here, because it just turns into the actual iframe. The problems I've been having are with the font size. I'm using font size="18" but it doesn't work. I've also tried several other methods. The code I use for font color works, so I don't know how to specify the font size. I also want to use a background color on my link to make it appear more like a button but I haven't been able to find a code for that. I'm a beginner and don't know much about coding so be patient with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the iframe source.
You can do it in css like this

```
.class {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

or as inline css

```
<p style="font-size: 18px;">Text here</p>
```